# Calendar.setTime() - null pointer exception : Android

Tags: android, calendar, simpledateformat

I need help with the below crash report. Strangely all the devices I have tested with does not generate this error. But my crash reports show around 60 of these in 2 weeks. Its obvious that its either limited to a particular make and device model or an OS version. My app is active on all the versions above 2.2, so I am in a fix to determine the actual problem. The log reports do not give me enough information to research. **App is live and running with more than 2500 installs" with 75% active installs** Thats and indication the issue being limited to a few users. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Background: 1) App displays a count down time to a particular event, takes a static time converts that into local time zone and calculates the differences. Displays 'Days','Hours','Min' and 'Sec'

2) A very similar error was reported on different schedule screens by few users.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{alfi.programs.olympics2012/alfi.programs.olympics2012.OlympicsMainScreen}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1997)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2018)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:139) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1124)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4636) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1325) at
>   java.text.SimpleDateFormat.formatImpl(SimpleDateFormat.java:536) at
>   java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:818) at
>   java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:376) at
>   alfi.programs.olympics2012.OlympicsMainScreen.getLocalTimeCountDown(OlympicsMainScreen.java:393)
>   at
>   alfi.programs.olympics2012.OlympicsMainScreen.countDownTime(OlympicsMainScreen.java:284)
>   at
>   alfi.programs.olympics2012.OlympicsMainScreen.onCreate(OlympicsMainScreen.java:55)
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4521) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1961)
>   ... 11 more

```
   private String getLocalTimeCountDown(Object date, Object time){

        String time1 = time.toString();
        String timeStart = time1.substring(0, 5);

        String fromDateString = date.toString() + " / " + timeStart + " GMT+01:00";

            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM / HH:mm zzz");

            Date fromDate = null;
            try {
                fromDate = (Date)formatter.parse(fromDateString);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oops.. there seems to be some problem... Report" +
                        " this immediately using the feedback link from the Main Screen.", 500).show();
            }
            TimeZone central = TimeZone.getDefault();
            formatter.setTimeZone(central);

            return  formatter.format(fromDate);
     }
```

Comment: And what does OlympicsMainScreen.java look like around line 393?

Comment: Can you please post your code so that we can see why it gives the exception ? Looks like something might be wrong with your SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: Jon & Swayam, I updated my code above. Thanks in advance, for looking into this.

Comment: It works fine on most of the devices, just not sure how the SDF would fail on some devices, the sad part is the Count Down Timer is crashing on initial launch on few, I am being hit badly on my reviews. If you guys have time and an Android device, you can check my app once, to get better understanding of what the issue might be. [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=alfi.programs.olympics2012)

Comment: How did you solve it? Can you post an answer? Hope you solved it quickly since you posted this

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suspect the problem is that there's been a `ParseException` - which you've caught and *completely ignored*. That's left `fromDate` as null, so when you then call `formatter.format(fromDate)` you're passing it a null reference, which you're not meant to do.

You should almost *never* have an empty catch block like that. What did you *want* to do if the text couldn't be parsed properly?

Comment: Jon, I actually have a Toast message in there. Just omitted it while posting here. But not sure Toast would help me. Any ideas, what should be my approach to catch the ParseException and do what with the Date. As it parses fine on my device, I have tested 1100 events manually. It doesnt crash. What is making it crash on few?

Comment: I dont have an alternative if the Date does not parse, I have a feeling there is something to do with the device timezone, thats the only data outside the code control.